# erro ao carregar um ProgressRing (Mahapps)

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um ProgressRing em uma Page no WPF que precisa ser exibido enquanto o Grid estiver sendo carregado (Objetivo: Mostrar ao usuário que está carregando) e depois ser desativado quando o carregamento do mesmo tiver sido concluído. Só que está dando esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
 public ClienteListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            carregar();
        } 
        
        public void carregar()
        {
            prProgresso.IsActive = true;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DataContext = App.container.GetService<IClientesListarController>();
            }).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                prProgresso.IsActive = false;
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", task.Exception);
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você está com problemas porque está executando isso em outra thread.

o .NET possui uma classe chamada [BackGroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), que fornece métodos para relatar o progresso do thread em um evento. O evento é chamado automaticamente no tópico que criou o BackgroundWorker (normalmente, o segmento UI).

Use esse evento "**ProgressChanged**" e atualize a barra de progresso nesse manipulador de eventos.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Thiago, mas não encontro esse componente na minha caixa de Ferramentas. Ele funciona com WPF mesmo?

Comment: adicione a referencia para using System.ComponentModel;
mais informações aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker